# RAZER SYNAPSE issue - binding modifier key only to mouse button is not working

Tags: mouse, keybindings, mouse-keys

I just bought Razer Naga Trinity, I tried to bind any modifier key only to mouse button on the Razer Synapse but it does not work, I hold it and press a key, it only types the key, it should launch the action. I also tried Macro with Command Left Down only on the macro, it behaves like sticky key. Have anyone got this working on their mouse?

**EDIT**

I was having problem with binding any modifier like mouse buttons 3, 4, 5 in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide us a screenshot where you are setting this in the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all. I finally resolved my issue, I have to install Karabiner extra software to resolve it. Now I have an issue with mouse scrolling speed too slow but it's ok I can bare with this.

https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/

The option must be checked
[image]